# Filtering High amplitude signal

Tags: filter, signal-processing, median

I have a little problem with this kind of signal[image]

As you can see , there's some missing values and later a big amplitude. What's the best way to filter this king of signal preventing ringing artifact? I was thinking about median filter.
Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to filter it?  Just to remove the noisy bits?

Comment: Yes!I'd like to remove the high frequency noise

Comment: It depends on what this signal represents and what you are trying to get rid of in your filtering operation. But for the missing value, you may want to include a hold (keep last value to fill the gap) and for the big values you may want to include an amplitude limiter to keep the values within an acceptable range.

Comment: A median filter will do it, or a simple moving average.  Are you just trying to make it _look_ smoother, or do you want to actually preserve some bandwidth of the signal?